# .Text() of select value in Select

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could I change the indicated line to use html of the selected option and not  the html of the entire tag. I know I can use .Val() to get value of the selected option but it's not an easy task to change the value of these results and I'm only interested in the html of the option.

```
$('#pickupSelect').on( 'change', function () {
    table
        .columns( 0 )
        .search( $(this).text() ) <-- Modify This line
        .draw();
});
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using `$(this).val()`?  That gets the value of the selected option.  Alternatively, you could use `$('option:selected', this).text()` to get the text of the selected option...

Comment: you want html or text? simply use .val() for value whats not so easy into in?

Comment: .Val() will give me the value of the option tag, I need the html of the selected tag.

Comment: You want the HTML (ex. `<option value='x'>x</option>`)? Why?

Comment: Because the HTML is the city name which I want to use as a search term but the value is the city code. The value is used in other parts of the application so using $('option:selected', this).text() works! Thanks.

Comment: so basically you needed text not HTML lol :)

Comment: Yeap, but text will give me the text of the entire select tag and not the selected option so cale_b solution works!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$(this).find("option:selected").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to get HTML

```
$( this ).html();
```